# NoIR raspicam v2.1 not seeing in infrared but NoIR raspicam v1.3 does

Tags: video, raspicam

I bought several raspicam v2.1's assumming they let IR in like previous versions, however I can barely see anything. See the picture for the comparison, top picture is v2.1 and bottom is v1.3

What is going on?

[image]

Comment: What settings are you using on the camera? You may need to crank up the shutter speed (which may require slowing the framerate) to get a longer exposure time

Comment: I was using default settings (like I've always done) then I've tried to adjust exposures and iso without much effect but I will try again tonight with lower lighting. Hard to believe that this issue isn't being posted everywhere, makes my night cameras completely useless!

Comment: auto_exposure (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=0 value=0
exposure_time_absolute (int)    : min=1 max=10000 step=1 default=1000 value=1000
exposure_dynamic_framerate (bool)   : default=0 value=0
auto_exposure_bias (intmenu): min=0 max=24 default=12 value=12
white_balance_auto_preset (menu)   : min=0 max=9 default=1 value=1
image_stabilization (bool)   : default=0 value=0
iso_sensitivity (intmenu): min=0 max=4 default=0 value=0
iso_sensitivity_auto (menu)   : min=0 max=1 default=1 value=1
exposure_metering_mode (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=0 value=0

Comment: Hmm, I've no idea what software those settings are from but it's not something I recognise. Try a capture with raspistill using the old and new modules - if you don't see any major illumination difference there then it's down to the software you're using (which is my suspicion and would also explain why the issue isn't being posted everywhere)

Comment: Those settings are from v4l2-ctl. I don't think it's my software because I'm using the same software on both cameras. I'm firing this command from my node code: ffmpeg -r 2 -strict -1 -s 1024x768 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video11 -f mpeg1video -b:v 1000k -r 2 -strict -1 http://stream-server/token/1024/768/